# How to calculate the column/bar segments width in WPF programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have googled many times with different keywords, but could not find an e-book for drawing different charts.

Ok my problem is I am drawing a column chart, I want the column chart to calculate the segment width based on the number of segments it has. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks and Regards,

Mawy

Comment: Have you considered (or are you already using) any charting toolkit? Otherwise I would strongly advise you to have a look at for example the charting functionality in the [WPF](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and [Silverlight](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) Toolkits; this would save you from a lot of the hassles of manually drawing your charts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the WPF toolkit, reference System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll . You can find some samples [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/charting-in-wpf/), it should be pretty simple, create your collection of KeyValuePair containing your data and then bind to the Key and the Value properties. More about the column charts [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/column-chart-in-wpf/). If you use this you won't need extra work for the width or height of the columns.

Comment: using toolkit is an way ok, but I want to render the charts using my own code and add some required features,,... any other ideas..